# yosemite, force reinstall, remote profile still exists

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Folks,
  I am trying to do a clean install of OSX Yosemite, and am running into an issue that there is a profile that is trying to get pushed down to the system.  This happens after the initial restart and a 12 minute install step.

I've looked everywhere, and am not able to find a command that I can run in terminal to remove this pesky thing.

Initial hunch is that the erase partition in disk utility does not remove everything that's on the machine....

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Was this machine originally purchased by a school or corporation or other large organization?

Apple has a service for large purchases where Apple records the serial numbers of the machines it ships to that customer, and then the customer can log into an Apple web portal to define a profile to be pushed to all their machines on first boot. This allows these machines to be auto-enrolled into a remote management system, so that they get on the site's network and can automatically be set up according to the organization's needs. It keeps these customers from having to use hundreds of technician-hours to unbox and reimage / set up machines.

Ask your site's sysadmin to log into the Apple portal and un-enroll your machine.

Comment: Yes, trying to bypass our shitty IT dept.   Got it installed, the only pesky thing that now happens is a pop up for device enrollment which is easy to disable I think, just have to google